# DbContext , Entity Framework 6, query for entity added in current session

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6, I have Star entity and I'm dealing with following simple code:

```
                      foreach(var name in names)
                      {
                        Star star = context.Stars
                            .Where(st => st.Name == name)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

                        if (star == null)
                        {
                            star = new Star();
                            star.Name = name;
                            context.Stars.Add(star);

                            star = context.Stars
                                .Where(st => st.Name == name)
                                .FirstOrDefault();

                            // Now it's NULL
                        }
                        }
```

I want to add to DB new Star only if it doesn't exists yet. Unfortunatelly, subsequent queries on the same session context without SaveChanges(), cant's find entities added in current session.
How can I solve it? (I don't want to save it in each step).

Comment: I meant context.SaveChanges(), not SaveAll()

Comment: You can edit your Post and replace SaveAll to SaveChanges.

Comment: What is your goal? You want to get exactly item from state or you just want to make a batch add?

Comment: See what `context.Stars.Local.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Name == name)` returns.

Comment: context.Stars.Local.FirstOrDefault() works for me, so should I check both collections?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework: Re-finding objects recently added to context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699648/entity-framework-re-finding-objects-recently-added-to-context)